# non-binary self balancing tree

Tags: data-structures, trees, balanced-search-trees

I'm looking for a tree data structure that allows to keep the tree balanced in high (minimum high as possible).

I mean, suppose a tree where:

- each node has a parameter k that is the maximum number of sons that can be attached to him, $0≤k≤N$
- all the operations will be about insert and delete (no search): it's just just important that every node know the son/s, I'm not interested at all in search (<0.1% of operations)

Would an adaption of RB-tree or AVL tree be a good idea for that task or there are better solutions (other data structures, other kind of tree, etc)?

Comment: What's wrong with the variants listed [on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Search_tree)? What are your exact requirements? Also, if you never search what on earth do you keep these data for?

Comment: By the way: do I infer correctly that you need/want a *sorted* dictionary/set implementation? I know of none for which search is more expensive than insertion or deletion, since they typically have to perform a search before doing either. So as long as you have deletes, I'm not aware of any answer beyond the classical answers (and their numerous variants).

Comment: I would not use the expression "self balancing" for RB and AVL trees. These data structures have a forced balanced structure. In self balancing structures the balance is not forced but should follow from searches (and other operations). Think splay trees.

Comment: In addition to the other helpful feedback, what does "balanced in high" mean?  How do you plan to evaluate answers?  Right now it looks like there are many possible answers, all equally valid.  What do you mean by "better"?  Better in what respect?  Do you have performance requirements?  Please edit the question to clarify all of these points.

Comment: If you see no way to improve your question, you can always post a self-answer with what you determined concludes your line of questioning.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a binary prefix-trie (critbit-tree). It's not exactly selfbalancing, but it never requires rebalancing and imbalance is limited. For example, with 64bit keys, the maximum depth is strictly 64. This is not exactly the lowest possible height, but maybe that requirement can be relaxed because no rebalancing ever occurs?

You can find an (my) implementation [here](https://github.com/tzaeschke/critbit).

Answer (score 0):

If your tree is a non-binary tree, and you have no limitations on the number of children, you can create a tree with a single root and infinite number of children. The height of that tree will be always 1.

```
class Node
{
    int data;
    SortedSet<int> children;
    function insert(int n)
    {
        children.add(n);
    }
    function delete(int n)
    {
        if(n exists in children) then delete n;
        else return error;
    }
}
```

**Application:**

```
Node root = new Node(5);
root.insert(8);
root.insert(10);
root.insert(20);
root.insert(-9);
root.insert(72);
root.insert(65);
root.delete(20);
```

The result will look like this:

```
             5
      /   /  |  \   \
   -9   8   10   65  72
```

Both `insert()` and `delete()` will take $O(\log (n-1)) = O(\log n)$ time in the worst case, $n$ being the number of nodes in the tree.

Comment: i've expressed bad the first condition

Comment: You have just reinvented the linear list, congratulations! And no, you don't get logarithmic operation time unless you use a worst-case logarithmic-cost `SortedSet` implementation, which is a catch-22. (Also, you have not improved on usual balanced search trees at all.)

Comment: @Raphael I am well aware it looks silly but that was what OP asked for :) I will edit it in a minute

Comment: @Raphael, I *think* that Java's `SortedSet` implementation uses a balanced binary tree scheme with $O(\log n)$ insert and delete, so it's not just a linked list.  I see this as an answer that meets all of the requirements and isn't a catch-22.

Comment: We can distinguish the tree that @newbie wants to store, vs the data structure that cagirici uses for storing child lists: the former is not a binary tree, even if the latter is.  So I see cagirici's answer as a clever (though possibly somewhat obvious) trick.  As newbie notes, we can't just use a red-black tree to store the former tree as that tree is non-binary and RB trees are for binary trees.  newbie wasn't sure how to adapt a RB tree to the non-binary case; this answer shows that you don't need to.  That's why I don't see it as a catch-22 or circular answer.

Comment: @D.W. The *idea* (two-level tree) ends up being a list (or worse). The proposed *implementation* (which, assuming an implementation like you say, looks nothing like the ASCII art in the answer) is "reasonable" implementation (why not use `SortedSet` directly?!) but does not answer the question: it does (probably) not provide a *non-binary* search tree. So no, I don't see a clever trick on the conceptual *or* programming level.